# The significance of the pronoun "It" in the given sentences

Tags: pronouns

1. I hate how people think they can do whatever they want.
2. I hate **it**, how people think they can do whatever they want.
3. I hate **it** how people they think they can do whatever they want.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?
What's the difference between the sentences mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

All three of your sentences have the same meaning and the the main difference is **stylistic**.

If anything, using **it** may emphasize what you are saying since a slight pause would occur after the **it** especially when signalled with a ','(comma).

Answer (score 0):

**It** there is known by several names, among them "dummy *it*".  **It** is a placeholder that refers to the state of affairs that will be expressed by the following clause which completes the meaning of the predication.

**I hate it when the press reports on politics as if it were a sport.**

**It** is like a delegate in programming.

Comment: I hate when the press reports on politics as if it were a sport.

If you had used this sentence as an example instead of the one you used, it would have still been correct, right?

Comment: "I hate when" is not ungrammatical, but neither is it perfectly idiomatic.  Although we do say "I hate when that happens!" here we'd probably say "I hate *how* the press..."